# Xamarin Android: Self-contradicting dependency requirements?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, dependencies

When trying to build my Android project in Xamarin Studio, I keep getting errors like these:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): 
Error: Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
Could not load assembly 'Mono.Android.Support.v4, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'. 
Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'Mono.Android.Support.v4.dll'
   at Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() (Akva20150407)
```

-

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): 
Error: Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
Could not load assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. 
Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll'
   at Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() (Akva20150407)
```

-

```
C:\progge\Apper\Akva20150407\Akva20150407\Act_MainGUI.cs(29,29): 
Error CS0433: The type 'Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity' exists in both 
'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v5.0\Mono.Android.Support.v4.dll' and 
'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v5.0\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll' 
(CS0433) (Akva20150407)
```

- I must add Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 to the MonoAndroid folder, or it will complain that it can't find it.
- I must add Mono.Android.Support.v4 to the MonoAndroid folder, or it will complain that it can't find it.
- If I add both, it will complain that FragmentActivity can be found in both packages.
- The packages were installed via NuGet.

It looks very much self-contradicting.... What on Earth am I supposed to do to get this working??

Comment: Did you install them via component store or nuget package manager? I had similar issue and reinstalling packages via nuget helped..

Comment: I have installed all packages via NuGet. I just tried to remove and reinstall Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, and now I got new errors:

Error: Duplicate managed type found! Mappings between managed types and Java types must be unique. First Type: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4'; Second Type: 'Mono.Android.Support.v4' (Akva20150407)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your Xamarin Studio

This bug was fixed in Xamarin Studio: 5.7.0.436. 
See bug report: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=24276